Why $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))=\mathbb{Q}(i,\zeta_n)$ if $n$ is odd?
I was trying to prove some properties to obtain that the degree of the extension of field $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))\vert\mathbb{Q}$ is $\varphi(n)$ when $n$ is an odd positive integer (being $\varphi$ the Euler's function).
It begins considering $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{4n})$, being $\zeta_m=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{m}}$ (it is true because $n$ is odd and $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{4n})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\zeta_{n})$). It is also true because $\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))=\frac{1}{2i}(\zeta_n-\zeta_n^{-1})$. Then it can be proven that $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))$ is a Galois extension because by The Fundamental Theorem of the Galois Theory, it is a subfield of a Galois extension with an abelian Galois group. Finally it want to prove that $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))=\mathbb{Q}(i,\zeta_n)$ and it sais to use the Hint: $$\sin(\frac{4\pi}{n})=2\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n})\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n}).$$
This is my problem, I don't know how to prove the inclusion $\mathbb{Q}(i,\zeta_n)\subset \mathbb{Q}(i,\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))$ when $n$ is odd (without using the degree that we want to prove and using specifically the hint). Using this equality of fields, by the Tower Theorem, we can obtain that the degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sin(\frac{2\pi}{n}))\vert\mathbb{Q}$ is $\varphi(n)$.
Can someone give me some help? Many thanks.

In case it's not already clear: to show that $\Bbb Q(i,\zeta_n) \subset \Bbb Q(i, \sin(2\pi/n))$, it suffices to show that $\zeta_n$ can be written as a polynomial over $i$ and $\sin(2\pi n)$

I suspect that it will end up being useful to show that $\zeta_n^2 \in \Bbb Q(i, \sin(2\pi/n))$ first, then use the fact that $(\zeta_n^2)^{(n+1)/2} = \zeta_n$.

in order to prove that $\zeta_n^2 \in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sin(2 \pi / n))$  first i need to show  that $\sin(4 \pi /n) \in \mathbb{Q}(i,\sin(2 \pi \ n))$. But im not sure how to proceed, could you help me?

Hint: $\prod_{k \in (\mathbb{Z}/n)^\times} (t - (\zeta_n^k - \zeta_n^{-k}))$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$
